# ArrayList element swapping not permanent

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of playing cards.

```
private ArrayList<VisibleCard> m_vecCards;
```

It has a private scope however upon accessing its members via:

```
public VisibleCard getCard(int n) {
    return this.m_vecCards.get(n);
}
```

I find that the elements are unsorted via the bubble sort algorithm:

```
public void sortCards() {
    int swapCounter, nIndex;
    int upperBound = this.m_vecCards.size() - 1;
    while(true) {
        swapCounter = 0;
        for ( nIndex = 0; nIndex < upperBound; nIndex++ ) {
            if ( this.m_vecCards.get(nIndex).getNumericVal() > this.m_vecCards.get(nIndex + 1).getNumericVal() ) {
                Collections.swap(this.m_vecCards, nIndex, nIndex + 1);
                swapCounter++;
            }
        }
        if ( swapCounter == 0 ) {
            for ( nIndex = 0; nIndex < 7; nIndex++ ) {
                Log.d("order", ""+ this.m_vecCards.get(nIndex).getNumericVal());
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a log function I can use to test the numbers to ensure my arrays are being sorted and it is the case that the array is being sorted, the results however are not permanent.

```
12-18 06:51:08.077: D/order(3636): 2
12-18 06:51:08.077: D/order(3636): 4
12-18 06:51:08.077: D/order(3636): 5
12-18 06:51:08.077: D/order(3636): 8
12-18 06:51:08.077: D/order(3636): 8
12-18 06:51:08.077: D/order(3636): 9
12-18 06:51:08.077: D/order(3636): 9
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 1
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 5
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 6
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 8
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 12
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 12
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 13
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 1
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 1
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 2
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 3
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 3
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 10
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 10
12-18 06:51:08.087: D/order(3636): 4
12-18 06:51:08.097: D/order(3636): 6
12-18 06:51:08.097: D/order(3636): 6
12-18 06:51:08.097: D/order(3636): 9
12-18 06:51:08.097: D/order(3636): 10
12-18 06:51:08.097: D/order(3636): 11
12-18 06:51:08.097: D/order(3636): 13
```

Essentially the elements within the ArrayList are not being swapped "permanently" as I would like.  I cannot understand this phenomena as I see nothing wrong with the code or the log debugging.

```
public void addCard(VisibleCard vc) {
    if ( this.m_humanAgent ) {
        vc.setPosition(-20, (this.m_vecCards.size() * 85) + 100);
        vc.rotate(1.57079633);
        vc.setup();
    }
    this.m_vecCards.add(vc);
    if ( this.m_vecCards.size() == 7 ) {
        this.sortCards();
    }
}
```

I am adding a total of seven cards for each player and after seven elements exist within the array, I invoke the sortCards() method but after outputting the cards, they do not appear in the order they ought to.

I render the output like this:

```
    for ( int n = 0; n < 7; n++ ) {
        this.m_flushRummy.getPlayer(0).getCard(n).draw(gl, m_bmTextureIds[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it does not appear GRAPHICALLY in the correct order! And here is the root cause:

```
vc.setPosition(-20, (this.m_vecCards.size() * 85) + 100);
```

You set the GRAPHICAL position of your cards BEFORE you sort them :) Then they are drawn in the correct order but not in the correct position.

Comment: lmao, you sir are a legend.  It could only happen to me.  a computer science degree and I'm still an idiot!

Comment: Thanks for admitting :) Btw, consider changing your design - the idea of having the VisibleCard in the collection is not good. This should be done separately in the presentation layer only.

Comment: I do not foresee the difference between using an ArrayList or a regular array, the point is the structure encapsulates many cards within the Player.  Alternatively the code would bloat without the collection.

Comment: I did not mean that. What I meant is that you should probably keep a collection of _Cards_ (and not _VisibleCards_) and after all the processing at the level of business logic (such as sorting) pass this collection to the view (GUI) layer witch will display it.

Consider what would happen if you wanted to change the way of displaying - you would have to copy and paste the code with the business logic instead of reusing it.

You have fallen into this stupid error *not* because you are an idiot :-), but because of a poor design from the very beginning. Mixing layers easily brings this.

Comment: So the very root cause is that you were adding, sorting etc. _VisibleCards_ instead of _Cards_.

Comment: yes I see your point.  VisibleCards extends from PlayingCard.  I will take it under advisement.

Comment: I would not even inherit VisibleCard from PlayingCard, but I would use VisibleCard rather _having_ a PlayingCard (an aggregation relationship). By this you will also implement a _kind of_ a "fly-weight pattern" :) Of course VisibleCard and PlayingCard _may_ implement a common interface (with methods such as getNumericalVal() implemented via delegation), but you will find that even this is not necessary. My view is that VisibleCard is to PlayingCard rather what a _frame_ is to a _picture_, or what a _wrapping paper_ is to a _Christmas gift_.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question, but do you need to implement the sorting algorithm by your own? If not, you could/should use the [Collections.sort(List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) or [Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method.

Also, as tom commented, this will be much faster than using the bubble sort.

Comment: this.  it'll be a lot faster than a bubble sort too.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the bubble sort algorithm in this topic, it works as illustrated in the log.  The problem is that any elements swapped by index in the arraylist are not permanent.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sortCards() {
int swapCounter, nIndex;
int upperBound = this.m_vecCards.size() - 1;
while(swapCounter > 0) {
    swapCounter = 0;
    for ( nIndex = 0; nIndex < upperBound; nIndex++ ) {
        if ( this.m_vecCards.get(nIndex).getNumericVal() > this.m_vecCards.get(nIndex + 1).getNumericVal() ) {
            Collections.swap(this.m_vecCards, nIndex, nIndex + 1);
            swapCounter++;
        }
    }
    upperBound--;
 }    
    if ( swapCounter == 0 ) {
        for ( nIndex = 0; nIndex < 7; nIndex++ ) {
            Log.d("order", ""+ this.m_vecCards.get(nIndex).getNumericVal());
        }
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: does not solve the problem.  The problem does not exist with the bubble sort algorithm, I conclude it is a bug in the java library.